# Generic static Vector data type in C with data segment memory

Tags: c, pic

Is it possible to create a generic Vector like data structure in C, with out using heap. Basically I need a array data type but a more generalized version on if it.

```
typedef struct {
 /* some data types*/
}TYPE1;

typedef struct {
 /* some data types*/
}TYPE2;

typedef struct _GCACHE_T
{
        const int element_size;
        const int count;
        struct _ELEMENT {
                        UBYTE           data[element_size];
                        BOOLEAN         is_valid;
                }element[count];
}GCACHE_T;

GCACHE_T f_cache1 = {sizeof(TYPE1), 15, {0} };
GCACHE_T f_cache2 = {sizeof(TYPE2), 10, {0} };
```

The above code will not compile but I have provided it for a better clarity on my requirement.

This would have been easy implemted provided heap memory was allowed to use. Since the code is meant for small micros heap memory usage is not allowed.

I could have used right away, but just checking if it can be done in a generic way.

```
TYPE1 f_cache1[15];
TYPE2 f_cache2[10];
```

The Vector will not grow in size. I could have also used a union but there is a memory trade off so not willing to use it.

Comment: What is the cost in memory if you use a union?

Comment: Normally I hate macros, but that might be an approach worth considering.

Comment: @HonkyTonk, a `union` takes as much memory as its largest element.

Comment: @Hristo And how much memory is used if you have _TWO_ arrays that are to contain instances of the types in question? I'd always go for the solution that is the easiest to understand and best maps to the problem. After doing that, looking at memory constraints become interesting.

Comment: @HonkyTonk, the question is tagged `pic` and this would imply that the OP is developing for a very resource constrained microcontroller device. (edit: I'm obviously blind - it is even written in the question itself)

Answer (score 0):

Such parametric (template, generic) types are not supported by C. You can take an approach similar to the one used by the BSD socket subsystem. There different network addresses (e.g. IP address and TCP/UDP port number) are stored in structures of varying size (depending on the address family, e.g. IPv4 structures are shorter than IPv6 ones) but with similar layout in the beginning. Whenever an address is required, a pointer to the generic `struct sockaddr` type is passed instead and the correct structure type is inferred from the address family of the socket.

C supports the so-called *flexible array members*, but it cannot be simply applied to your case because not only is the number of `struct _ELEMENT` entries different, but the size of those elements could differ depending on the value of `element_size`. This makes it hard to compute the address of `cache.element[i].data[j]` in a portable way whithout refering to the actual type. What you can do is put an additional field in the beginning of the `GCACHE_T` type that helps you identify the true size of `struct _ELEMENT`:

```
typedef struct _GCACHE_T
{
    int element_size;
    int count;
    size_t element_stride;
    struct _ELEMENT {
        BOOLEAN         is_valid;
        UBYTE           data[];
    } element[];
} GCACHE_T;
```

`element_stride` keeps the size of the concrete element type (including any padding). Note that `is_valid` is moved before `data[]` as C allows only the last element of a structure to be a flexible one.

You would then create specific types, e.g.

```
typedef struct _GCACHE_TYPE1_15_T
{
    int element_size;
    int count;
    size_t element_stride;
    struct {
        BOOLEAN         is_valid;
        UBYTE           data[sizeof(TYPE1)];
    } element[15];
} GCACHE_TYPE1_15_T;

GCACHE_TYPE1_15_T f_cache1 = {
    sizeof(TYPE1),
    15,
    // An awful hack to obtain the size of a structure member
    sizeof(((GCACHE_TYPE1_15_T *)0)->element[0])
};

do_something((GCACHE_T *)&f_cache1);
```

Macros would come handy if you need to declare many different cache types. Now in `do_something()` you can compute the address of `f_cache1.element[i].data[j]` because you know the offset of the `data` field inside `struct _ELEMENT` and you can compute the offset of `element[i]` because the size of a single element is stored in the `element_stride` field.

Yeah, I know, it is a real pain... And I am not sure how much of the pointer arithmetic required works on a Harvard architecture device like PIC.